# A quickly evaporating degreaser that does not ruin plastics?

Tags: solutions

I was wondering if there is a quickly evaporating solution that effectivly removes fat from glasses, but does not ruin plastic or metal. That is any eyeglass frame material..

Answer (score 0):

Diethyl ether, found in gasoline engine starter sprays, is a very effective solvent for fats, and it does not attack *most* plastics too rapidly. Try a bit on an out-of-sight location to be sure it does not damage the frame or lenses.

Note that some engine starter fluids contain an oily lubricant, which would defeat your purpose. **Also note that ether is *extremely* flammable.** A gently pressed spray can releases only small amounts at a time, but it will still catch fire if there is ny source of ignition nearby.